# Ignore items of a specific type in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, winforms, drop-down-menu

I am trying to uncheck a menu's all checkable ToolStripMenuItem items with

```
foreach (ToolStripMenuItem item in filtersMenu.DropDownItems)
{
   item.Checked = false;
}
```

ToolStripMenuItem's are all checkable but the problem is compiler gives an InvalidCastException, the loop is trying to operate on ToolStripSeparator items too, how can i fix this, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Just check if the item is a separator in a conditional query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the answer of RononDex, which is perfectly good. You can also us this:

```
foreach(ToolStripMenuItem item in filtersMenu.DropDownItems.OfType<ToolStripMenuItem>())
{
    item.Checked = false;
}
```

### Edit:

If I am not mistaken, RononDex's code should work if modified to this (use `ToolStripItem` instead of  `ToolStripMenuItem`:

```
foreach (ToolStripItem item in filtersMenu.DropDownItems)
{
    if (item is ToolStripSeparator)
        continue;

    item.Checked = false;
}
```

And a bit shorter:

```
foreach (ToolStripItem item in filtersMenu.DropDownItems)
{
    if (item is ToolStripMenuItem)
        item.Checked = false;
}
```

This will work because the `DropDownItems`-property is of the type `ToolStripItemCollection`. This collection holds items of the type `ToolStripItem`. Also if you look at the inheritance hierarchy of both the `ToolStripMenuItem` and the `ToolStripSeparator`, you'll see they both inherit from `ToolStripItem`.

More reading:

- [**ToolStripDropDownItem.DropDownItems Property**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdownitem.dropdownitems%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, by the way the answer of RononDex doesn't work, i tried it before even posting this...

Answer (score 7):

Just add an if statement that checks the type of your item:

```
foreach (ToolStripItem item in filtersMenu.DropDownItems)
{
    // Move to next item if ToolStripSeparator
    if (item is ToolStripSeparator)
        continue;

    item.Checked = false;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work, if it worked that way, it wouldn't be a problem  anyway, because my loop is foreach (TOOLSTRIPMENUITEM item in filtersMenu.DropDownItems)

Warning 1 The given expression is never of the provided ('System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparator') type

Comment: Ofcourse i tried that, it is like the first thing that comes to mind, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: @imdrunkisuppose I overread the mistake I made. Thanks for Abbas for pointing this out. Edited my answer